# "Connection to github.com closed by remote host" when pushing

Tags: git, github, git-push, openssh

I have a project where every time I `git push` to my GitHub account using SSH keys (on Windows), the command line hangs for several minutes, and then I eventually get the error `Connection to github.com closed by remote host.`  I can do `git pull` or `git fetch` successfully.  I can also do `ssh -T git@github.com` successfully.

I've been pushing successfully to this project for a while.  I think this problem started when I switched to use OpenSSH as my SSH agent and configured it to use two different keys for different SSH accounts.  However, I've disabled the separate keys (I renamed my `.ssh\config` file) to test, and I still have the same problem.

I tried cloning this project to another location on my computer, updating it, and doing a `git push` and that works correctly from the newly cloned repository.

Here are the results of `git remote show origin` from my original repo.

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:MyUserName/MyRepo.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:MyUserName/MyRepo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop tracked
    master  tracked
    test    new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop merges with remote develop
    master  merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop pushes to develop (fast-forwardable)
    master  pushes to master  (fast-forwardable)
```

Here are the results of `git remote show origin` from my newly cloned repo.  Note that the `test` branch is a new branch that I created so I didn't overwrite `master`.

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:MyUserName/MyRepo.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:MyUserName/MyRepo.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    develop tracked
    master  tracked
    test    tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
    test   merges with remote test
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
    test   pushes to test   (up to date)
```

Comment: This *kind of* sounds like a networking issue, but if you can push successfully from another clone on the *same machine*, that seems less likely. Windows has some mysterious file system behaviors, so maybe it's something to do with one of those.

Comment: Can you run the failing push in Git Bash with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push origin master` (or whatever branch) and edit your question to include the output?

Comment: @bk2204 I tried it using the command you gave me in Git Bash and it pushed successfully on both my `master` and `develop` branch.  Maybe the problem is with OpenSSH?

Answer (score 41):

I can't explain the long hang time, but the eventual `Connection to github.com closed by remote host` message is likely caused by your SSH connection with GitHub timing out. I recently helped a coworker solve a similar issue where our Husky pre-push hook was taking a long time to complete on her machine. By the time the hook finished, she received the same `Connection to github.com closed by remote host` message.

We found the solution was keeping her connection alive by setting values for `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` in her `.ssh\config` file. For example, adding the following settings would send a null packet to the server every 60 seconds (keeping the connection alive) for 30 rounds. This would buy you 30 minutes of connection.

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
  ServerAliveCountMax 30
```

You can adjust the the values however you see fit for your use.

Comment: Same problem & solution pushing to bitbucket.org with a Husky pre-push hook

Comment: For me this file was in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Pushing with `--no-verify` helped me get through, although that's just bypassing the pre-push hook. 

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [wmcb91's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65818657/5033601), you can explicitly set the time directives under the GitHub host. See the [github ssh documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) for adding your identity info in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *.github.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 30
```